# Deriving the logical subject of an infinitive subordinated to a passive main clause

Tags: passive-voice, subjects, infinitive-clauses

I am wondering whether the logical subject of an infinitive should be the same with the subject of the main clause if **the infinitive is used as an adverb of purpose in a sentence**. As for this matter, I found two sayings.

In the website http://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-purpose, it is said that "The infinitive of purpose can **only** be used if the doer of the action expressed by the infinitive is **the same as** the subject of the main clause."

While in the website http://www.rit.edu/ntid/rate/sea/processes/infinitives/grammatical/subjects/purpose it is said that "the logical subject of the infinitive **is not** the subject of the main clause" , for example "The technicians were fired by the management to reduce costs." and "The technicians were fired to reduce costs."

Based on the two, I am wondering whether I could come to the conclusion that if the main clause is **active** then the logical subject of the infinitive **should be the same as** the subject of the main clause, and if the main clause is **passive** then the logical subject subject of the infinitive **should not be the same as** the subject of the main clause. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is admirable.

You may combine the two partial formulas by distinguishing between a clause's Subject (a syntactic role) and its Agent (a semantic role):

> The infinitive of purpose ascribes the purpose which it expresses to the Agent of its head clause.

- ACTIVE: [<sub>SUBJECT</sub>The management<sup>AGENT</sup>] fired [<sub>DIRECT OBJECT</sub>the technicians<sup>PATIENT</sup>] **to reduce costs**.
- PASSIVE: [<sub>SUBJECT</sub>The technicians<sup>PATIENT</sup>] were fired by [the management<sup>AGENT</sup>] **to reduce costs**.

  The Subject is the Agent in the active sentence and the Patient in the passive sentence, but in both cases the purpose is ascribed to the Agent.